# What is a `red vertex` and what is a `blue vertex`?

Tags: graph-theory

I showed the following question on an exam:

> let $G(V, E)$ connected indirected graph with positive weights.
>
> any vertex is colored with either blue or red.
>
> Claim: if edge $(u, v)$ is the lightest from the edges $(x, y)$ that x has difference colors  from y (for exaple, x is red and y is blue),
>
> Then there is MST of $G(V, E)$ that contains $(u, v)$.

My question is, what is a blue vertext and what is a red vertex?

I know only about red and blue edges. thanks !

Comment: Um... do you know colorings? You can color sets, it doesn't matter if they are edges or vertices. A coloring of $V$ would be a function $f : V \to \{ \text{red} , \text{blue} \}$, i.e.  you assign a color to each vertex.

Comment: You color the vertices instead of the edges. It is exactly what it sounds like: an assignment of a color to each vertex.

Comment: Somebody down-voted this question. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd have written "every vertex is colored red or blue" rather than "any . . .".

It just means that they're dividing the set of all vertices into two disjoint subsets and calling the members of one set "red" and those of the other "blue".

Comment: Are you 100% sure? So just by coloring, how can I know if $G(u, v)$ is in a MST?

Comment: @Billie: it is indeed true for any possible way of colouring (assuming both colours are used of course), no restriction whatsoever.

Comment: The claim, then, is that no matter how you assign colors to vertices, there would be such a minimum spanning tree.

Comment: @Gina So why the hell he misled us .. thank you very much both